# Volume in MIDI track keeps resetting

Tags: midi, cubase

I imported a MIDI track, rearranged it, changed the volume of VSTi Instrument but that volume keeps changing by itself when it plays a new part (DAW: Cubase).

What is going on?

Comment: @Tetsujin - questions about particular products are NOT currently off topic.  If you wish them to be off topic, the correct way to do this is not to make inaccurate VTC votes, it is to go to meta and try to change the consensus of how the site should operate, otherwise a minority of people could simply decide they don't like something and start closing away.  VTC is not intended to push your own personal desires, but rather to help moderate according to community standards.

Comment: @AJHenderson There is a distinction between 'questions about a product' & 'questions better addressed by the developer or the product manual'. Let's try not to turn this into the Steinberg helpline, or 'how do I use Midi?' Anyway, I think it's probably simpler if I just stop participating in this SE & let it become what it wants to be without me.

Comment: This question was about how midi works and understanding how the signals and formats work is pretty important stuff to being able to work with sound.  If the question was about how to, say, access the help in Cubase, or how to get automatic updates to apply, then I'd be more inclined to agree with you, but if they are trying to do something sound design/production related, then I don't see why it would be off topic.  If we exclude every question that COULD be answered somewhere else, then there is nothing left.

Answer (score 1):

Your MIDI parts contain CC (Controller Change) and PC (Program Change) messages at the start of each clip.

You need to ignore/remove the CC/PC information.

In Cubase you can do that during recording with the Input Transformer, and you can remove it from clips afterwards in the Logical Editor, or the Key Editor.

Here is how to do it using the Key Editor (notice the CC #7 Volume - this is most likely the culpritt). Simply delete the information or set the value as desired.:

[image]